# Изящная современная вещица. Нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Возник спор: нужна ли запятая между определениями?

> Недавно я купила одну изящную(,) современную вещицу.

Comment: С запятой лучше.

Comment: Интересно, на какой вы стороне.

Comment: Я больше склоняюсь к запятой...

Comment: Значит, вы молодец.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо никакй запятой: ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ХАРАКТЕРИЗУЮТ ВЕЩИЦУ С РАЗНЫХ СТОРОН: степени красивости и времени изготовления.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разве "*изящная и современная вещица*" плохо звучит?

Comment: А Розенталя вы читали? У него сказано, что  "между однородными определениями, не связанными союзами, ставится запятая, если они характеризуют предмет с разных сторон, но по условиям контекста они объединяются каким-либо общим признаком (внешним видом, сходством производимого ими впечатления, причинной связью и т.д.). Тут легко можно найти такой признак, например "привлекательность".

Comment: Я тоже в данном случае за запятую.

Comment: Здесь как раз подходит: **сходством производимого ими впечатления**.

Comment: Нет. Это кагбэ фрагмент диалога. Некто говорит: сейчас такой прелести не сыщешь. Некто другой ответствует: а мне удалось  обнаружить новодел, но придраться не к чему (типо того). Изящество вещицы - её привлекательность. Современноть - время производства.

Comment: Современность в наше время тоже привлекательна, люди опасаются старомодности. Здесь можно вставить И, а значит, и можно написать с запятой, это факт, даже Розенталь не нужен. Рекомендую проанализировать звучание. Вы же знаете, что оно существенно отличается? Ещё есть целесообразность определения фразы: "*быстрая дорогая машина*" — нельзя сказать, что дорогие машины делятся на медленные и быстрые, поэтому нужна запятая. В нашем примере не настолько, но тоже есть такое, из-за чего не звучит идеально. У Розенталя немного есть об этом.

Comment: Стоп, современность — это не время производства/изготовления. В магазинах не продаются старые вещи. Современность — это соответствие новым стандартам.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пусть "современность — это соответствие новым стандартам". Но при чём тут изящество?

Comment: *сходством производимого ими впечатления* — хорошее впечатление.